# I'm not able to bind jquery function to current div

Tags: jquery, bind, jquery-hover

I have several divs with the same ID's (#viewport_outer) , on hover I'm trying to show a Icon thats placed in another div (#icon-hover) ::: I'm able to get the Icon to show (opacity 1) :::

The problem is I'm not able to bind the function for every (#viewport_outer) div ::: if I hover over any div (#viewport_outer) the icon (#icon-hover) shows on the first (top) div only :::

Here's my HTML :

```
<div id="viewport_outer" class="default">
    <div id="viewport">
        <div id="icon-hover"></div>
            <p> Some content ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery, I've tried altering it but just cant get it working ::: Any help would be appreciated :::

```
jQuery('#viewport_outer.default').hover(function() {
        jQuery('#icon-hover').css({opacity:1});},
    function() {
        jQuery('#icon-hover').css({opacity:0});
})
```

Comment: "..with same ID's". ID's should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique. Use the class-attribute instead.

```
<div id="viewport_outer" class="outerElement default">
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="icon-hover"></div>
            <p> Some content ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery('.outerElement').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.icon-hover').css({opacity:1});},
    function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.icon-hover').css({opacity:0});
})
```

Comment: Good I understand ID's should remain unique ::: If this is not possible is there no other way to achieve this ::: As I'm not able to create unique ID's for each div

Comment: See my example. It should do what you want. It is using classes instead of ids.

Comment: @ hacksteak25 You're a champion , Thank you SOOOOOO much :::

Answer (score 2):

ID's must only be used once in any given HTML document.

Use a class name instead since these can be applied to multiple elements on the same page.

```
<div class="viewport_outer default">
```